# Cannot open JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a button in my HTML, once click on the button, I want to open a JQuery Dialog.
I have a version of code which works fine, but I just want to reorganize the code, seems like there's something wrong with it since the dialog cannot be displayed anymore.

the version that works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#dialog_trigger').on("click", function() {
       $('#dialog').load('index.php', function() {
          $('#dialog').dialog({
           *********(somehow I must remove 'autoOpen: false' here, otherwise it also stops working) ********

              position: 'center',
              width : 480,
              height : 320, 
              modal : true
          });

        });
      });
  });

</script>

<body>
<button id="dialog_trigger">Click me</button>
<div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
```

the code that doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $('#dialog_trigger').on("click", function() {
       $('#dialog').load('index.php', function() {
          $('#dialog').dialog("open")
       });
    });

   $('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'center',
    width : 480,
    height : 320, 
    modal : true
   });

});

</script>

<body>
<button id="dialog_trigger">Click me</button>
<div id="dialog"></div>
</body>
```

Please help me correct it, thanks.

Comment: `$('#dialog').dialog("")` I don't think that's right, what are you really trying to do there?

Comment: opps, sorry, copy error, originally is $('#dialog').dialog("open"). fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly move the signature for the `dialog` to outside the click event.

Then in the click event you can use

```
$('#dialog').dialog("open")
```

to show the dialog

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mGH56/)**

**Code**

```
  $('#dialog_trigger').on("click", function() {
       $('#dialog').load('index.php').dialog("open")
    });

   $('#dialog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     position: 'center',
     width : 480,
     height : 320, 
     modal : true
   });
```

Comment: Sorry, there's a copy error before, I do call the "$('#dialog').dialog("open")" inside the click event, and define the dialog outside. However, it doesn't work, I mean, after I clicking the button, nothing happens.

Comment: and Sushanth, I want to load a web page into the dialog, please see my first version of code, can you help fix the second one according to what I want in the first one?

Comment: @user1453951.. Why don't you try this `$('#dialog').load('index.php').dialog("open")`

Comment: huh, that's what I want, thanks!!! Btw, do you know what's the difference if I put "open" to the dialog() or not? Is it a function parameter?

Comment: `open` is a method available on the `dialog object` ..  If you just call `.dialog()` instead of specifying a method , it will just create a new instance of dialog box which is not what you want

Comment: Sorry but I have a further question, what's the problem with my second code? .load('index.php'),function({$('#dialog).dialog("open")};) I just put the .dialog("open") inside the callback function of load(), in theory it should work... kinda strange